# Android design spec

Tags: android

If in the android design spec says padding has to be 10px of TextView for example, how would you represent that in you .XML layout as we know in .XML we use dp
for example:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="8sp"
      android:textStyle="italic"
      android:id="@+id/myName"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:text="myname"
      android:paddingBottom="14dp" < is this 10 px?>
      android:paddingEnd="16dp"/>
```

here android:paddingBottom ="14dp" (14 here is just assumed number)so how do I know that 14dp or other any number will represent 10px in actual screen

Comment: Can you add a source on your 10px value?

Comment: Android does support **PX** unit. Ex. **android:paddingBottom="10px"**

Comment: You could put 10px, but dp is more preferred because it scales for different screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to wrong you. But there is no such documentation that says that some padding/margin/height/width/dimension must be in *px (pixels). Android Design Specification describes all the dimensions in dp (dip). I recommend you to use [Material Design](https://material.google.com/) Specification for Android.

But if you got that from somewhere (tell him to change it), there are many online sites that can convert pixels to dp. Like:

1. [Pixplicity.com](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/)
2. [Angrytools](http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/)

or you can the below code to convert pixels to dp:

```
// context = this; for Activities
// context = getActivity(); for Fragments
Resources resources = context.getResources();
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
float dp = px / ((float)displayMetrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
```

Hope this will help you all a lot.